# landscape, portrait

Tags: android, android-layout

i have been searching this site for an answer but i cant find one . my android app isnt swapping from portrait to landscape in my emulator it just shows a sideways portrait screen.
I have made a layout and layout-land folder with matching xml names and so on . but it doesnt seem to pick up on the layout-land versions. i do not have an onConfig() function or anything so i was wondering if anyone can help???

**mainpage.xml layout-land**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_title_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_title"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/start_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/start_button"
                android:textColor="@color/text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/help_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/help_button"
                android:textColor="@color/text" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/extra_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/extra_button"
                android:textColor="@color/text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stop_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/stop_button"
                android:textColor="@color/text" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_title_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_title"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_button"
        android:textColor="@color/text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/help_button"
        android:textColor="@color/text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/extra_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/extra_button"
        android:textColor="@color/text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stop_button"
        android:textColor="@color/text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.MC.ChemPal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".main"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.MC.ChemPal.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".mainpage" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.MC.ChemPal.MAINPAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Extra"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.MC.ChemPal.EXTRA" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".help"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.MC.ChemPal.HELP" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".search_page"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.MC.ChemPal.SEARCH_PAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**java**

```
package com.MC.ChemPal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class mainpage extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button start_button, help_button, extra_button, stop_button;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

        start_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        help_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help_button);
        extra_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.extra_button);
        stop_button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_title_text);

        start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent openSearchPage = new               Intent("com.MC.ChemPal.SEARCH_PAGE");
                startActivity(openSearchPage);
            }
        });
        help_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent openHelp = new Intent("com.MC.ChemPal.HELP");
                startActivity(openHelp);
            }
        });
        extra_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent openExtra = new Intent("com.MC.ChemPal.EXTRA");
                startActivity(openExtra);
            }
        });
        stop_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onStop();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: have you deactivated autorotation in the emulator ?

Answer (score 1):

It is an emulator bug, when you try your activity start in landscape mode you will see that it will load mainpage.xml from layout-land ,

android:screenOrientation="landscape"

but ctrl+f12 doesnt work, it is a bug

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189

Comment: it has it but i'm new so i'm not to good with these posts but i have the button on both . ty

Comment: Hi it is a emulator bug, ctrl+f12 doesnt work. To test your landscape mode modify manifest.xml. I edited my answer.

Comment: If it helps to you , pls dont forget to mark answer as accepted, http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png  . Thanks,